# How to select n-th elements with progression?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select child elements in some progression. But using only CSS.

For example, need to select element of:

1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 and so on...

or

1, 3, 9, 27, 81 and so on...

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">some content</div>
    <div class="child">some content</div>
    <div class="child">some content</div>
    ... thousands probably of such children ...
    <div class="child">some content</div>
    <div class="child">some content</div>
    <div class="child">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can’t do that with a fixed number of rules. There’s probably some limit to the number of elements, though, so you could write them manually up to that.

Comment: `-nth` pseudoclasses only accept equations of the form `a + b<n>`. What you described are quadratic and cubic equations

Comment: You could do it with javascript or SCSS, not with pure CSS.

Comment: Yes, with nth power

Comment: @Adriani6 so can you make example in SCSS for this. So it will be probably answer I seek (as pure CSS can not do it)?

Comment: @A.Denis Sure thing, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using SCSS as requested you can do the following (while loop):

```
$i: 1;

@while $i < 100 {

    .test:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        background: blue;
    }

    $i: $i * 3;

}
```

That would compile and provide the following output:

```
.test:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue; }

.test:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue; }

.test:nth-child(9) {
  background: blue; }

.test:nth-child(27) {
  background: blue; }

.test:nth-child(81) {
  background: blue; }
```

This demonstrates your second use case. As for the first one you would just change the formula that calculates the `$i` to `$i: $i * 2;`